# Get results from mysql query into an integer array?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a php embedded mysql query as follows:

```
$query_sample = mysql_query(" 
SELECT left FROM sampleTable WHERE right  = 1 
UNION 
SELECT right FROM sampleTable WHERE left  = 1 
");
```

where both the "right" and "left" columns are integers.

After this query is executed I want the result set to be assigned into an integer array in php.
Is there an effecient approach to converting the results of a query into an integer array??

QUESTION:

I basically want to be able to ask the question: "Is $x in $results_array" after the results set from the query has been assigned to $results_array and $x is any integer.

Any help appreciated guys....

Comment: If `x` is a column in `sampleTable` you should do this with SQL.

Comment: Please don't write tags in question titles.

Comment: @Jason $x is not a column in sampleTable it is just testing whether $x is within the result set.

Comment: If it's in the result set, doesn't that mean it's in the table?

Comment: I'm still confused... Let me rephrase - if `x` is a value you can test against a column in `sampleTable` you should do this with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run through the result and build the array.

If you really need the result to be integers, just pass it through `intval`. A quick snippet follows.

```
$query_sample = mysql_query(" 
SELECT left FROM sampleTable WHERE right  = 1 
UNION 
SELECT right FROM sampleTable WHERE left  = 1 
");
$result = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query_sample, MYSQL_NUM)){
    $result[] = intval($r[0]);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Edit: Sorry. I messed up with things. Just corrected it.

---

> I basically want to be able to ask the
>   question: "Is $x in $results_array"

Do it using MySQL! It is optimized for doing such things fast. Especially if you have set the indexes right.

Answer (score 0):

php is a loosely typed language, so generally, it doesn't *really* matter whether it's "10" or 10.  php will properly evaluate it as an integer if you were to do like

```
$x = "10";
$y = $x * 10; // assigns 100
```

..but if you really want to find out if it *can* be an integer, you can use [is_int()](http://www.php.net/is_int)

Or if you want to specifically type cast it, you can do like

```
$x = intval($x);
```

or

```
$x = (int) $x;
```

**edit:** (response to comment below)

re: "getting the results into an array"

When you perform a query, you get a result *source* returned.  In order to put the returned data into an array, you need to loop through the result source and assign to an array.  Example:

```
$result = mysql_query($querystring);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $array[] = $row['columnname'];
}
```

Comment: I am more concerned with the first part of the question, which involved getting the result set from the query into an array. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tomalak: No, right question..it just sounded like he was concerned about the results being a string instead of an int, so I was responding to that.